# Excel File Suddenly missing all but one worksheet

Tags: excel

13MB Excel .csv file suddenly only shows one worksheet. No password and worksheets are selected to show. I've tried all the remedies I understand from the web. Hoping there is a programming approach to accessing the worksheets not showing.

Comment: A CSV file cannot contain multiple worksheets and hence nothing can be hidden within it. If you try to save a workbook with multiple sheets as a .CSV it will only save the active sheet (and you will get multiple warnings in the process).

Comment: When you save an Excel file as a CSV, the original xlsx is still there. Why don't you open that?

Answer (score 1):

A [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (Comma-separated values) file is in fact a text file. It cannot contain more than 1 worksheet as in an Excel file. When you save an Excel file as CSV you can save only 1 worksheet at a time.

Comment: Saved that file for a week as a .csv with extra worksheets via "Control S" and selecting "yes" per dialog re: keeping the file in its original (csv) format.. You're saying that's not possible, so I searched for an .xlsx version across my entire drive and didn't find anything. I do know the date and time when the file was last saved. Currently searching for a text string I know is in one of the "missing" worksheets. Also, excel graphs from those worksheets were cut and pasted into a .ppt file. Changes I made in Excel automatically populated into Powerpoint. Really appreciate your help!